# How to make ''sudo launchctl limit' change permanent?

Tags: macos, mojave, launchd

I have a background job that failed due to `too many open files` error.

To fix it, I  have to kill the job, then run the following

```
sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 10240 10240
```

before restarting it.

Is there any way I can make the `launchctl limit maxfiles` change permanent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a launch daemon to run that command on every startup. Create `/Library/LaunchDaemons/private.maxfiles.plist` with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>private.maxfiles</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>launchctl</string>
            <string>limit</string>
            <string>maxfiles</string>
            <string>10240</string>
            <string>10240</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Just a note-to-self: the change will take effect after the machine restarted.

Answer (score 1):

Launchd has two keys — `HardResourceLimits` and `SoftResourceLimits` —  that can be used to place limits on the resources of jobs. They take a dictionary of integers, so you can add something like the following to your launchd plist to get a permanent solution:

```
<key>HardResourceLimits</key>
<dict>
    <key>NumberOfFiles</key>
    <integer>500</integer>
</dict>
```

This should cap out the number of files that process has open at 500.

I'm not really certain what the difference between 'soft' and 'hard' limits are, though the man page for launchd.plist says (cryptically):

> NumberOfFiles
>
> The maximum number of open files for this process.  Setting this value
>   in a system wide daemon will set the sysctl(3) kern.maxfiles
>   (SoftResourceLimits) or kern.maxfilesperproc (HardResourceLimits)
>   value in addition to the setrlimit(2) values.

sysctl(3) has no man page on my machine, and it's too early in the morning for me to go do a google search. I'll suggest, though, that what you're really looking at is a coding error, and you should fix this in the daemon, not rely on launchd. launchd likes to have flexible control over things, and would rather that users avoid dictating too much.

Comment: AFAIK sysctl(3) is only available when Xcode is installed: (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/share/man/man3/sysctl.3) `man sysctl -S 3`.

Comment: @klanomath: I have Xcode, but I probably don't have my man page viewer set properly to find that file.